# How to add a function in const Target = props => {

Tags: reactjs

How do I add a function to connect to one of my components onChange? Creating a function like this returns an error code of 'cardActionResponse' is not defined.

What the benefit of using a const class like this?

```
const Target = props => {

    const { markAsDone } = useContext(ItemContext);

    const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop({
        accept: 'Item',
        drop: (item, monitor) => console.log(item),
        collect: monitor => ({
            isOver: !!monitor.isOver()
        })
    })

    //Cannot do this. How else can I make a function to connect to CreateVideoCard?
    cardActionResponse = (event) => {
        console.log(event);
    }



    return (
        <div className="target top80 right30" ref={drop} style={{ backgroundColor: isOver ? 'black' : '' }} >
            <TitleDescription class="z1"/>
            <div class="right10 left10">
                <CreateVideoCard onChange={this.cardActionResponse} />
                <CreateDescriptionCard></CreateDescriptionCard>
                <CreateAudioCard></CreateAudioCard>
                <CreateTermsCard></CreateTermsCard>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Target;
```

Comment: You're missing a const: `const cardActionResponse =`. Also there's no this in an arrow function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Don't wanna be too picky, but just wanted to point out that the "this" keyword is available in arrow functions, it just points to the parent context.

Comment: @Nicolas that's more accurate, yes; thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Functional components don't have it's own context (`this`), so you should simply use `const` variable.
Please use

```
const cardActionResponse = (event) => {
        console.log(event);
    }
```

and then

```
<CreateVideoCard onChange={cardActionResponse} />
```